# A Tabbed calculator in python with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, tkinter, closure

For learning purposes, I have written a small calculator app on Python, tkinter.
I want to check if my design is on best practices for OOP, And seek advice on Nested functions

For easy readability, I have only included the Addition functionality, same logic can be applied to Subtract, Multiply etc..with few changes to the #calculations.py

---

My entry:

```
#app.py

from tkinter import Tk
from all_tabs import AllmyTabs

class App:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        app.title('My Calculator')
        # app['bg'] = '#f8bbd0'
        app['bg'] = '#ff80ab'
        app.minsize(325, 200)
        app.maxsize(325, 200)

        tab_addition = AllmyTabs(app)

root = Tk()
my_app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Next I'm setting tabs for each window, this snippet will include a Add and Subtract Tab, more can be added if needed

```
#all_tabs.py

from tkinter import ttk
from calculations import my_addition

class AllmyTabs(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(app)
        self.app = app
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('TFrame', background='#f8bbd0', )
        #===========================================#  
        self.tab_pannel = ttk.Notebook(self.master,)
        self.tab_pannel.grid(pady =40, padx=10)
        #===========================================#  
        self.addition_tab = ttk.Frame(self.tab_pannel, width=250, height=250, padding=10 )
        self.tab_pannel.add(self.addition_tab, text='    Add    ',)
        my_addition(self.addition_tab)
        #===========================================#  
        self.subtraction_tab = ttk.Frame(self.tab_pannel,padding=10)
        self.tab_pannel.add(self.subtraction_tab, text='    Subtract    ')
        my_subtraction(self.subtraction_tab)
```

---

Now This is where I'm having the troubles, `my_addition()` function works as expected, but if you check, you can see that I have used nested functions. So I decided to ask for help on how can I manage without coming up with extra nests.

Closures are great to continue where needed, but in my case I think it adds up extra complexity to the code and it gets harder to read.

```
#calculations.py

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import N, E, S, W, NSEW, IntVar, StringVar

def my_addition(app):

    def now_adding():
        if len(addition_entry.get()) == 0:
            out_put_number.set('Enter a number')
        elif len(addition_no.get()) == 0:
            out_put_number.set('2 numbers are needed')
        else:
            result =  int(addition_entry.get()) + int(addition_no.get())    
            out_put_number.set(result)
        
        addition_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        addition_no.delete(0, 'end')

    def only_numbers(char):
        return char.isdigit()

    vcmd = app.register(only_numbers) 

    addition_entry = tk.Entry(app,  validatecommand=(vcmd, '%S'))
    addition_entry['validate'] = 'key'
    addition_entry.grid(column=1, row=0,)

    plus_lbl = tk.Label(app, text='  +  ', bg='#f8bbd0')
    plus_lbl['font'] = 20
    plus_lbl.grid(column=2, row=0, )

    addition_no = tk.Entry(app, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, '%S'))
    addition_no.grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=E)

    result_label = tk.Label(app, text='Result: ', bg='#f8bbd0')
    result_label.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

    out_put_number = StringVar()
    result_output = tk.Label(app,  bg='#f8bbd0', textvariable=out_put_number)
    result_output['font'] = 20
    result_output.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3,)

    addition_btn = tk.Button(app, text='Add', command=now_adding, state='normal')
    addition_btn.grid(column=3, row=1, pady=10, sticky=E )
#===============================================================================#
#===============================================================================#   
def my_subtraction(app):
    pass
```

I have tried using classes on the #calculation.py module, but then again extra complexity comes up.

Because I'm learning and trying to understand the underlying principle of OOP, the more readable a code, the more easily I can comprehend it

Is there a way to refactor the code and keep it simple as possible??

Any Advice is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: "more can be added if needed" Could you simply share the full (unedited) thing with us? Keep it structured like it is, dump the full thing at the bottom of the question. There's a limit of 65k and a bit characters, I'm sure you'll stay under that. But the extra context may help with better answers.

Comment: @Mast, the above code will work and run perfectly,  the part which I have excluded  will follow the same logic. for example. if you check the `#all_tabs.py`: `addition_tab` and `subtraction_tab` have a similar structure, same structure can be applied to a `multiply_tab` or a `division_tab` etc...my problem rises in `#calculations.py`, where I have written my full code, I stopped on `my_addition()` because its the function that I want to simplify, once it is simplified the the same structure will be applied to 'my_subtraction()` with few changes, Hope I made myself clear, thanks

Comment: Your question is at the brink of getting closed for lack of context.

Comment: I'm sorry it lack context,But  My full code is exactly as #app.py and #all_tabs.py, I'm trying to implement, A FUNCTION AT A TIME, not to write the whole thing, since am still learning it helps me to debug easily..